# Change the style of an item in an array on press by comparing with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of objects in an array (**tagList**). When clicked, the object is pushed into another array (**selectedTags**).

```
var selectedTags = [];

export default class RegisterTags extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            tagList: [],
        }
    }

    insertTag = (tag) =>{
        selectedTags.push(tag)
    }

    render() {
        var tagsToRender = this.state.tagList.map((tag) => {
            return(
                <TouchableOpacity key={tag.id} onPress = {() => {this.insertTag(tag) }}> 
                    <View style={styles.tagStyle}>
                        <Text style={styles.tagText}>{tag.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })

        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.ScrollViewContainer}>
                    {tagsToRender}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to change the style of the View for the tag that is present in the **selectedTags** dynamically. I thought of using lodash's `_.includes(selectedTags, tag)` to check if the tag is included in the selectedTags, but this does not work. How can I change the style dynamically for the selected tags when the tag is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

simply check if tag exist in selected tags and assign the selecedTag style :

```
var tagsToRender = this.state.tagList.map((tag) => {
        var selected = selectedTags.indexOf(tag) > -1
        var style = selected ? styles.selectedTagStyle : styles.tagStyle
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity key={tag.id} onPress = {() => {this.insertTag(tag) }}> 
                <View style={style}>
                    <Text style={styles.tagText}>{tag.name}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    })
```

Comment: Although the item is pushed into the selectedTags on pressing, this does not change the style of the pressed tag Item.

Comment: ah change the placement of selectedTags and put it in state to force rendering and when adding a new tag : `this.setState({
   selectedTags:this.state.selectedTags.concat([tag])
})`

Comment: Its working now, but the performance is very slow. The time it takes to change the style is very long. Is there anyway to tweak this?

Comment: yes. You can create a component called Tag for example and has it's own state and have method to change this state from parent component. this should let you change a tag state (selected or not, so rendering correspondent style) without rendering other tags .